# Disabled button in WPF

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm trying to do something very simple and basic. Correct me if I'm wrong:

Think of a simple button and then methods associated to it as following. However, I'm getting either none (a disabled button) of if I change returning type on DrawShapeCanExecute() then I would get an error message as:

*bool WpfApplication8.DrawingCanvas.DrawShapeCanExecute(object, System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs)' has the wrong return type*

```
public static RoutedCommand DrawShape = new RoutedCommand();


private void DrawShapeCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true; 
} **//Isn't this enough to make it enable?**



private void DrawShape_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

its xaml portion has:

```
<Button Margin="0,2,2,2" Width="70" Content="Line" 
        Command="{x:Static local:DrawingCanvas.DrawShape}"
        CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
            AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DrawingTarget}"
        CommandParameter="Line">           
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this statement in MainWindow.xaml.cs solves it:

`public IInputElement DrawingTarget { get { return _canvas; } }`

The point is that we are adding a menubar not on form but on a canvas.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark the event as handled:

```
e.CanExecute = true;
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: if you mean using both e.CanExecute = true and e.Handled = ture ... yes done it but it is a no go.

Comment: @amitkohan, did you try to put a breakpoint in the event handler to check that it was called?

Comment: Good question! yes I placed a break-point on `      this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(DrawingCanvas.DrawShape, DrawShape_Executed, DrawShapeCanExecute));`  what happens here is that when I hover mouse over **DrawShapeCanExecute** its hint shows this message: DrawShapeCanExecute(...) has the wrong return type

Comment: @amitkohan, DrawShapeCanExecute should return void. And put the breakpoint inside DrawShapeCanExecute

Comment: @amitkohan, well, the event is probably not wired up correctly... But there's no way to guess from the code you posted; could you edit your question to show the code of the command binding and event subscription? (whether you did it in XAML or code-behind)

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx I see you need to bind the CanExecute and Executed handlers. It would be something like:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:DrawingCanvas.DrawShape }"
                Executed="DrawShape_Executed"
                CanExecute="DrawShapeCanExecute" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Button Margin="0,2,2,2" Width="70" Content="Line" 
    Command="{x:Static local:DrawingCanvas.DrawShape}"
    CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
        AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DrawingTarget}"
    CommandParameter="Line">           
</Button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about that since I have defined it in `<ResourceDictionary>` block not in a regular `<Window>` block. file itself is located under a folder in project **/Resources/Views/AppToolbar.xaml** and it is a ResourceDictionary